# How in Qt i can insert several queries into sql in one time?

Tags: c++, sql

In SQL, I have foreign keys in tables so my insert one by one doesn't work. How can I insert several queries in one time?

```
query.prepare("ISERT INTO job_format (job_format_id, location, work_schedule)"
              "VALUES (:job_format_idValue, :locationValue, :work_scheduleValue)");
query.bindValue(":job_format_idValue", lastJobFormat + 1);
query.bindValue(":locationValue", ui->tableWidgetData->item(i,4)->text());
query.bindValue(":work_scheduleValue", ui->tableWidgetData->item(i,3)->text());
query.exec();

query.prepare("INSERT INTO vacancy (vacancy_id, salary, company_id, profession, job_format, contacts, experience) "
              "VALUES (:vacancy_idValue, :salaryValue, :company_idValue, :professionValue, :job_formatValue, :contactsValue, :experienceValue)");
query.bindValue(":vacancy_idValue", lastVacancy + 1);
query.bindValue(":salaryValue", ui->tableWidgetData->item(i,5)->text());
query.bindValue(":company_idValue", currentID);
query.bindValue(":professionValue", ui->tableWidgetData->item(i,0)->text());
query.bindValue(":job_formatValue", lastJobFormat + 1);
query.bindValue(":contactsValue", ui->tableWidgetData->item(i,6)->text());
query.bindValue(":experienceValue", ui->tableWidgetData->item(i,1)->text());
query.exec();

query.prepare("INSERT INTO skills_for_vacancy (line_skills_for_vacancy_id, vacancy_id, skill) "
              "VALUES (:line_skills_for_vacancy_idValue, :vacancy_idValue, :skill)");
query.bindValue(":line_skills_for_vacancy_idValue", lastLineSkill + 1);
query.bindValue(":vacancy_idValue", lastVacancy + 1);
query.bindValue(":skill", tableSkillsMas[i]);
query.exec();
```

This is my foreign keys
[image]

Comment: Insert elements in right order according to dependencies?

Comment: Column names are writed in right order the problem is that i can't insert this 3 queries one by one because they have general foreign keys, i have to insert all of them in one time somehow.

Comment: I don't talk about column order, but query order. Not sure which field is foreign key, I assume `company_id` in `vacancy`, so table company should be filled before table `vacancy`.

Comment: Added foreign keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First line ISERT INTO not INSERT...